# How to write eloquent joins in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to write eloquent joins in laravel

Jobs Table

```
id
job_title
sector_id
```

Sector Table

```
id
Sector
```

Sector Model

```
class sector extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['sector_name'];


    public function newapaper(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\newspaper_jobad');
    }
}
```

Jobs Model

```
class job extends Model
{
    public function sector(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\newspaper_jobad');
    }
}
```

When I execute following query

```
$var = newspaper_jobad::with('sector')->get();;

dd($var);
```

it gives me this result

```
[
        "id" => 1
        "job_title" => 1
        "sector_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2017-08-19 16:46:43"
        "updated_at" => "2017-08-20 13:14:02"
        ]
```

but what I want to use joins in a eloquent way not direct query builder class

```
 [
            "id" => 1
            "job_title" => 1
            "sector_id" => 1
            "sector" => Governamnet
            "created_at" => "2017-08-19 16:46:43"
            "updated_at" => "2017-08-20 13:14:02"
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add field to `with()` argument:

```
$var = newspaper_jobad::with('sector.Sector')->get();
dd($var);
```

Comment: not worknig
Call to undefined relationship [sector_name] on model [App\Models\sector].